# Matplotlib legends in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to put legends inside each one of the subplots below.
I've tried with plt.legend but it didn't work.

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(xtr, color='r', label='Blue stars')
ax2.plot(ytr, color='g')
ax3.plot(ztr, color='b')
ax1.set_title('2012/09/15')
plt.legend([ax1, ax2, ax3],["HHZ 1", "HHN", "HHE"])
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot]
With the suggestion from atomh33ls:

```
ax1.legend("HHZ 1",loc="upper right")
ax2.legend("HHN",loc="upper right")
ax3.legend("HHE",loc="upper right")
```

The legend position is fixed, however it seems to have a problem with the strings, because each letter is placed in a new line.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: For the strings issue: try using the label keyword in the `plot()` command instead.

Comment: When strings become their individual letters, it's because Python treats strings as sequences of letters.  If you need to tell Python that a string is a string that shouldn't be broken, you can put it into a one element list `["HHZ"]` or tuple `("HHZ",)`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This should work:

```
ax1.plot(xtr, color='r', label='HHZ 1')
ax1.legend(loc="upper right")
ax2.plot(xtr, color='r', label='HHN')
ax2.legend(loc="upper right")
ax3.plot(xtr, color='r', label='HHE')
ax3.legend(loc="upper right")
```

Comment: Yes, it places the legend in the correct place. Thanks!The only problem is, it puts each letter in one line. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: Here you will find more details: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Answer (score 32):

What you want cannot be done, because `plt.legend()` places a legend *in the current axes*, in your case in the last one.

If, on the other hand, you can be content with placing a comprehensive legend in the last subplot, you can do like this

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
l1,=ax1.plot(x,y, color='r', label='Blue stars')
l2,=ax2.plot(x,y, color='g')
l3,=ax3.plot(x,y, color='b')
ax1.set_title('2012/09/15')
plt.legend([l1, l2, l3],["HHZ 1", "HHN", "HHE"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you pass to `legend` not the axes, as in your example code, but the lines as returned by the `plot` invocation.

#### PS

Of course you can invoke `legend` after each subplot, but in my understanding you already knew that and were searching for a method for doing it at once.

Comment: sorry to interrupt, but may i confirm that the key that makes the position of the legend at the last plot are `sharex = True` and `sharey = True` ?

Comment: How do you put this comprehensive legend at the bottom of the figure?

Comment: @user7986928 no

Answer (score 8):

This does what you want and overcomes some of the problems in other answers:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["HHZ 1", "HHN", "HHE"]
colors = ["r","g","b"]

f,axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

# ---- loop over axes ----
for i,ax in enumerate(axs):
  axs[i].plot([0,1],[1,0],color=colors[i],label=labels[i])
  axs[i].legend(loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

... produces ...
[image: subplots]