# Plotly legend next to each subplot, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly, plotly-dash

After noticing that there was no answer to this question at the moment, I would like to know if anyone has an idea how to:

1. Have a legends for each subplot.
2. Group legends by name. (Ex: for different subplots, all have the same two curves but with different values).

Here's my Plotly script:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
nom_plot=[]

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6],name='1',showlegend=True)
nom_plot.append('GRAPH 1')
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70],name='2',yaxis='y2')
nom_plot.append('GRAPH 2')
trace3 = go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800],showlegend=False)
nom_plot.append('GRAPH 3')
trace4 = go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000])
nom_plot.append('GRAPH 4')
trace5 = go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70])
nom_plot.append('GRAPH 5')

print(trace1)



fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=4, cols=2, subplot_titles=(nom_plot))

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig['layout']['xaxis1'].update(title='xaxis 1 title')
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace4, 2, 2)
fig['layout']['yaxis3'].update(title='yaxis 3 title')
fig.append_trace(trace5, 3, 1)


fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(
    overlaying='y1',
    side='right', 
    anchor='x1',
    # domain=[0.15, 1],
    range=[2, 6],
    # zeroline=False,
    showline=True, 
    showgrid=False,
    title='yaxis 3 title'
)

fig['layout'].update(height=1000, width=1000, title='Multiple Subplots' +' with Titles')


plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='multiple-y-subplots6.html')
```

This what I obtain (Using Plotly Script above):

[image: Exemple Made by using Plotly]

And this is what I want (Made by Pygal):

[image: Exemple Made by using Pygal]

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in the 2nd question but as for the 1st
take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016904/matplotlib-legends-in-subplot

Comment: @Veltz I am talking about Plotly, not Matplotlib

Comment: https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-subplots-with-individual-legends/1754

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to create an HTML file that merge sevral charts offline rendered as html files:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fichier_html_graphs=open("DASHBOARD.html",'w')
fichier_html_graphs.write("<html><head></head><body>"+"\n")

i=0
while 1:
    if i<=40:
        i=i+1


        #______________________________--Plotly--______________________________________


        color1 = '#00bfff'
        color2 = '#ff4000'

        trace1 = go.Bar(
            x = ['2017-09-25','2017-09-26','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29','2017-09-30','2017-10-01'],
            y = [25,100,20,7,38,170,200],
            name='Debit',
            marker=dict(
                color=color1
            )

        )
        trace2 = go.Scatter(

            x=['2017-09-25','2017-09-26','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29','2017-09-30','2017-10-01'],
            y = [3,50,20,7,38,60,100],
            name='Taux',
            yaxis='y2'

        )
        data = [trace1, trace2]
        layout = go.Layout(
            title= ('Chart Number: '+str(i)),
            titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=15,
            color='#7f7f7f'
            ),
            paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',

            yaxis=dict(
                title='Bandwidth Mbit/s',
                titlefont=dict(
                    color=color1
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color=color1
                )
            ),
            yaxis2=dict(
                title='Ratio %',
                overlaying='y',
                side='right',
                titlefont=dict(
                    color=color2
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color=color2
                )

            )

        )
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Chart_'+str(i)+'.html',auto_open=False)
        fichier_html_graphs.write("  <object data=\""+'Chart_'+str(i)+'.html'+"\" width=\"650\" height=\"500\"></object>"+"\n")
    else:
        break

fichier_html_graphs.write("</body></html>")
print("CHECK YOUR DASHBOARD.html In the current directory")
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used two side by side **Div** elements to emulate Plotly **subplot**. Doing this way, we have independent legends. However, if we want to share an axis, we should do it manually:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.Div(['YOUR FIRST GRAPH OBJECT'],
                 style = {'float':'left', 'width':'49%'}) ,
        html.Div(['YOUR SECOND GRAPH OBJECT'],
                 style = {'float':'right', 'width':'49%'})   
                ])
```