# Solution for scatter legend of subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, legend, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a problem i can´t handle. I tried several things but its not working. Or at least I am to dumb to get the solution idk.

T create subplots with a for loop and every time create it with data from a subarray. For each scatterpoint i create a different colour (around 13 scatterpoints per subplot).

Now the thing is I want to create a legend for every subplot to show which colour is realted with which point.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(15, 15), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .35, wspace= .3)

C = np.array([[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [139, 0, 139], [255, 140, 0], [216, 112, 147], [238, 130, 238], [119, 136, 128], [0, 0, 0], [139, 69, 19]])
axs = axs.ravel()

for i in range(9):



    SingleWeldLayer = np.where(WeldArray1[:,0] == PlotLayerStart + i)
    Last = np.amax(SingleWeldLayer)
    First = np.amin(SingleWeldLayer)

    DynArray = WeldArray1[First:Last+1]

#    print(DynArray)

    axs[i].scatter(DynArray[:,3], DynArray[:,2], c = C/255)

    axs[i].set_title('Layer: '+ str(PlotLayerStart + i))
    axs[i].set_xlabel('MF_LargeCoil_TargetPosition', fontsize=8)
    axs[i].set_ylabel('HF_SmallCoil_TargetPosition', fontsize=8)


plt.show()
```

Can someone help me with creating an legend for every single subplot?

[Current scatter plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7nd5.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016904/matplotlib-legends-in-subplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib legends in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016904/matplotlib-legends-in-subplot)

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, add `axs[i].legend(loc="upper right")`

Comment: I already tried this. but it replies everytime that 'No handles with labels found to put in legend.'